# Flow and Mechanics of Earth, homework question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow

I don't understand the first question. Does anyone know how to solve the first questions. I'm stuck on calculating the upper and lower permeability of the reservoir.

[image]

Comment: I assume they are asking for an upper bound to the superficial velocity.  What are your thoughts on this so far?